# How can I tell what processes are using a file under Java in Windows?

Tags: java, windows, file, process

We have a scheduled task written in Java that is failing on Windows platforms because sometimes the files it needs to delete are still in use.  Is there a way from within Java that I can see what processes are using a file and get information on them?

I thought I would add that I am willing to use JNA or JNI if necessary, and I assume it is going to be.

Comment: Not sure if you will be able to do this without becoming dependent on the OS, thus limiting the portability of your application.

Comment: Yes, this is going to be a Windows only solution, but it's a Windows only problem.  The same automatic task already runs perfectly fine on hundreds of Linux servers.  If we figure it out, we will not execute the code for this solution on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I asked a similar question on Github for the JNA project and **@matthiasblaesing** wrote a code to accomplish this.

The code is [**here**](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/issues/657#issuecomment-242941713).

It prints a list with all the running processes in the format: `<exe>: <type>: <path>`.

Answer (score 2):

One dirty way to do it is to run your application with administrative privileges and invoke a command utility such as [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) using a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: That might be best, as Handle and similar utilities probably encapsulate all the complicated work of working across different Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the excellent [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to do this, and it's not limited to Java processes.

See [this posting](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232830) for details.  I don't know how to invoke this functionality from java, however.

Comment: Do you have information about the licence ? Is it open source ?

Comment: We have process explorer, but I need a way to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

My own preliminary answer (please, someone do better!):

Ideally, I'd like to learn how to programmatically do what tools like Process Explorer, unlocker, handler, etc., do, and then call that from Java with JNA or similar.  But it looks like that involves data structures that change for each Windows release, so it sounds very fragile.  The system call involved appears to be named NtQuerySystemInformation.

It looks like in cases like we are dealing with, the preferred approach for Windows Vista onward is to use the "restart manager API," which triggers a system restart, clearing all open filehandles.  (source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sv/netfxbcl/thread/37dc9843-2583-41fc-8260-b78183aa4bed)  We sure don't want to do that, if we can help it.

Comment: The purpose of the Restart Manager is to *avoid* a restart, not to trigger one.

Comment: Thanks.  I am probably misunderstanding, and I will reread it.