# Renaming a file throwing Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException:

Tags: java, file

I'm looking into a directory for creation of new files by using [WatchService.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)Whenever a new file is created or coming into this directory I need to change name of that file.

I have following code for that

```
Path pathfolder=Paths.get("D:\\tempm\\watch");
        WatchService watcherService=FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        pathfolder.register(watcherService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);

        System.out.println("Watching that directory");
        boolean valid=true;
        do{
            WatchKey watchKey=watcherService.take();
            for(WatchEvent<?> event:watchKey.pollEvents()){
                WatchEvent.Kind kind=event.kind();
                if(StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE.equals(event.kind())){
                    final String fileName=event.context().toString();
                    if(fileName.endsWith(".jar")){
                    System.out.println("File created--"+fileName);
                    File oldFileName=new File("D:\\tempm\\watch\\"+fileName);

                        File destFile=new File("D:\\tempm\\watch\\"+fileName.substring(0,fileName.lastIndexOf("."))+"_processing.jar");
                        File path=new File("D:\\tempm\\watch\\");
                            if(!fileName.contains("_processing")){
                        Files.move(oldFileName.toPath(), destFile.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE,StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING); //Line Number 45
                        FileDeleteStrategy.FORCE.delete(oldFileName);
                        System.out.println("Old file deleted");
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
            valid=watchKey.reset();
        }while(valid);
```

When I'm pasting a file for the first time into that directory it got renamed successfully.If I add any file for second time it is throwing exception.I have no Idea why it is giving this exception.Need some help.

My Output

```
Watching that directory
File created--dom4j.jar
Old file deleted
File created--dom4j_processing.jar
File created--watchplc.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemException: D:\tempm\watch\watchplc.jar -> D:\tempm\watch\watchplc_processing.jar: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.move(Unknown Source)
at ext.gt.test.MonitorDirectory.main(MonitorDirectory.java:45)
```

Comment: Some one is using the file, preventing the rename. Use ProcExplorer(Sys internals)  to find  who has handle to it.

Comment: @Jayan Can you give me docs link for `ProcExplorer`?. I have not used that before

Comment: all goodies are at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: @Jayan Can you tell if there any java class can able to check what process is holding my file?And how should I check\kill that?

Comment: IMHo Plain java will not help. You may write some native code.  see some hints at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11104916/how-can-i-tell-what-processes-are-using-a-file-under-java-in-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program fails because `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE` only tells you that a file has been created and not that a process has stopped writing to the file or released the file handle. You can replicate the error by creating a simple program yourself.

```
public class FileCreator
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        new FileCreator().go();
    }

    public void go()
    {
        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try
        {
            File file = new File("d:/tempm/watch/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jar");
            fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
            {
                // first write
                fileWriter.write(String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(fileWriter != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // data is flushed and file handles are closed
                    fileWriter.flush();
                    fileWriter.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that a file is created as soon as the first `write()` is encountered. This program still has a handle to the file and continues to write to it until the stream is flushed and closed. Your other program picks up this file to move it before the stream is close on this one.

You need a system that tells you if a file has been completely written to the directory you are watching, before you attempt to make a `move` on the file.

Comment: Can you explain me how `StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE` relate with holding a file which is going to be created there in my code?I have not used any FileWriter or reader here

Comment: The point is not that you may or may not have used a `FileWriter`. An application is writing a file to that directory. I was trying to illustrate that creating a file is faster than writing to it completely and flushing it. Until this is done, you cannot move the file.